# Missing `x-cache-proxyname` from response header in scrapoxy

Tags: ruby, scrapy

I've been scraping some URL having throttling limit using scrapoxy. Whenever it blocks the URL after a certain time, it won't return x-cache-proxyname in the response header so that I can't stop that particular instance and create another one. Below is the full header response.

```
{"content-type"=>["text/html"],
 "content-length"=>["110778"],
 "connection"=>["close"],
 "date"=>["Sun, 27 May 2018 18:20:37 GMT"],
 "last-modified"=>["Wed, 12 Apr 2017 09:12:05 GMT"],
 "etag"=>["\"c465e20f1a2c5681318061d5321e2368\""],
 "accept-ranges"=>["bytes"],
 "server"=>["AmazonS3"],
 "x-cache"=>["Error from cloudfront"],
 "via"=>["1.1 7f43afdd7e6d9ba0ebc0701aab572252.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"],
 "x-amz-cf-id"=>["dYWVQe6v1cb7JLQy0WnJE9KP0mtZGyrumbNdORIyaOo7MeaOExpf2w=="]}
```